# Effective Field Theory approach: Radiated Power from Multipole Moments

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Recently I have been reading Andrea Ross' paper "Multipole Expansione at level of the Action" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4750).

The second chapter focuses on the case of a scalar field and an expression for the multipole expanded source term of the action is given by Eq.(9). At this point, I was wondering if there is a way to find Eq.(12) in the same paper using a diagrammatic approach (and if so, how to "build" such diagram): something analogous is done for example in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0701129, where Eq.(2.40) can be found from the diagram appearing in Eq.(2.26). In the latter, I do not understand how the "Feynman rule" is found though.

Going back to Ross' paper, chapter three focuses instead on the case of Electromagnetism: the multipole expanded action is given in Eq.(46) and an amplitude for the photon emission can be extrapolated (Eq.(51)): once again, my question would be how can I do this using a diagrammatic approach and how I should "build" such diagram.

Any kind of help or suggestion of possible references would be appreciated!